# JDBC Requests High CPU at JMeter Client

Tags: jdbc, jmeter

I was implemented a JDBC test plan with my database on a web-server (I built a web server by myself). When I start a simple request from JMeter Client (Ex: `SELECT * From link d WHERE d.`link`LIKE '%com%'`), then the CPU of JMeter would high usage (90-100%) for a long time (~5 mins, but I set my test plan in 6s :(. And on server side, CPU high very short time - 5-7seconds (I think this time for the query to database). I tried to change the HEAP in jmeter.bat to more than 1024m, but is wasn't successful.

Can you help me to solve this problem?

Comment: Hello,
You should check how many rows your query returns. 
How many Threads are you setting ?

Answer (score 0):

I'd run EXPLAIN PLAN on that SQL query.  You're likely to see a TABLE SCAN because of the way you wrote the WHERE clause.  That takes a lot of time, more as your table grows, because it requires that you examine each and every record.